# Types of property 'boundaryGap' are incompatible

Tags: typescript, echarts

Try to create the option for `echarts`, when I try to merge the `initialXAxis` and `xAxis` options, got an TS type error:

```bash
Type '{ type: "category"; data: any[]; axisLabel: { formatter: (value: string) => string; }; scale?: boolean | undefined; boundaryGap?: [string | number, string | number] | undefined; splitNumber?: number | undefined; ... 40 more ...; categorySortInfo?: OrdinalSortInfo | undefined; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ....' is not assignable to type 'XAXisOption | XAXisOption[] | undefined'.
  Type '{ type: "category"; data: any[]; axisLabel: { formatter: (value: string) => string; }; scale?: boolean | undefined; boundaryGap?: [string | number, string | number] | undefined; splitNumber?: number | undefined; ... 40 more ...; categorySortInfo?: OrdinalSortInfo | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'XAXisOption | XAXisOption[] | undefined'.
    Type '{ type: "category"; data: any[]; axisLabel: { formatter: (value: string) => string; }; scale?: boolean | undefined; boundaryGap?: [string | number, string | number] | undefined; splitNumber?: number | undefined; ... 40 more ...; categorySortInfo?: OrdinalSortInfo | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '(AxisBaseOptionCommon & { gridIndex?: number | undefined; gridId?: string | undefined; position?: CartesianAxisPosition | undefined; offset?: number | undefined; categorySortInfo?: OrdinalSortInfo | undefined; } & { ...; }) | (CategoryAxisBaseOption & ... 1 more ... & { ...; })'.
      Type '{ type: "category"; data: any[]; axisLabel: { formatter: (value: string) => string; }; scale?: boolean | undefined; boundaryGap?: [string | number, string | number] | undefined; splitNumber?: number | undefined; ... 40 more ...; categorySortInfo?: OrdinalSortInfo | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'CategoryAxisBaseOption & { gridIndex?: number | undefined; gridId?: string | undefined; position?: CartesianAxisPosition | undefined; offset?: number | undefined; categorySortInfo?: OrdinalSortInfo | undefined; } & { ...; }'.
        Type '{ type: "category"; data: any[]; axisLabel: { formatter: (value: string) => string; }; scale?: boolean | undefined; boundaryGap?: [string | number, string | number] | undefined; splitNumber?: number | undefined; ... 40 more ...; categorySortInfo?: OrdinalSortInfo | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'CategoryAxisBaseOption'.
          Types of property 'boundaryGap' are incompatible.
            Type '[string | number, string | number] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.
              Type '[string | number, string | number]' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.
```

But I didn't set the `boundaryGap` property. The [xAxis.boundaryGap](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.boundaryGap) documentation says:

> The `boundaryGap` of category axis can be set to either `true` or `false`. Default value is set to be `true`.

Users should not be demanded to explicitly specify the `xAxis.boundaryGap` property.  Is this a TS type bug in `echarts` library?

```
import { EChartsOption } from 'echarts';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

const getOption = (data: any[]): EChartsOption => {
    const initialXAxis: EChartsOption['xAxis'] = {};
    const xAxis: EChartsOption['xAxis'] = {
        ...initialXAxis,
        type: 'category',
        data: data.map((item) => item.issueTime),
        axisLabel: {
            formatter: (value: string) => dayjs(+value).format('HH:mm'),
        },
    };

    const series: EChartsOption['series'] = [];

    return {
        xAxis,
        series,
        yAxis: {},
    };
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgUQMIAsCGsDOB5MGYCAOzgF84AzKCEOAcgFMBjLXBgbjgHoe4YATzBMcALjgBWAHQAWaQGYAUKEiw4AE0yCAVjmq16DLbpxclSlqRzwA5kxgEipOAF44ACi0xMEzCUEAbQBdAEoJNHYYfEJiMlcAPkQlAEgrEhs4YBJgIkwAGwANAEEAD2BxFAxsaKc4wIZSsoqGYLdEck5U9Mym8srImpjnEga+lrb3BFSU6Tns3OACkv6AGhmhEQkGFkwYJltoQQZ1lJTvX009zGkQTDAPD1ymEFC3JOeQaQqcAFcmAAqoCYoVOKUw-QAMpgAEZMfISaZnFJUaB3GD7KASDwANwK-wkNig2Vsb0SV1MHgA1Hj8v9QtJUVB0R4GAAJNliEAgBigmbkU6dCxpazwHBMYmiCLVXB1UgNcWSsyTOAhLqpKAOX5QMhIlLjHBgxXAURgwTNSoIAWpIVCoA)

package versions:

```json
"echarts": "^5.4.3"
```

Answer (score 1):

It says that there's an issue with the `boundaryGap` property. The `boundaryGap` property of the x-axis in ECharts is expected to be either a `boolean` or `undefined`, but in your code, you're trying to merge it with an array `[string | number, string | number]`.

You need to explicitly specify the `boundaryGap` property in the `initialXAxis` object, and then merge it with the `xAxis` object

```
const initialXAxis: EChartsOption['xAxis'] = {
    boundaryGap: true, // or false, depending on your use case
};
```

Comment: It works. But I think the default value of `xAxis.boundaryGap`  is set to be `true`. Users should not be demanded to explicitly specify the  `xAxis.boundaryGap` property. Is this a TS type bug in `echarts` library?

Comment: I didn't see where I was trying to merge it with an array `[string | number, string | number]`. The error says it, but I didn't see it from the code.